# how to save entire json from kafka topic to Cassandra table, using Spark streaming

Tags: json, apache-spark, stream, apache-kafka, rdd

This is my json data , i am sending this to kafka topics , reading using spark rdd , 
and save into cassandra.

```
[{
"sensor": "swapSensor",
"sendtime": "2016-09-15T11:05:01.000Z",
"data": [{
"@context": "Context"
         }]
}]
```

this is my cassandra's table
**`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS event(sensor text,sendTime text,count bigint,entireJson text, PRIMARY KEY ((sensor)));`**

i wanted to push entire json(raw) data to table's column **entireJson**.

this is my code.

```
object StreamingData {

  var count = 1


  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val Array(brokers, topics, cassandraHost) = Array("1.11.22.50:9092", "c", "localhost")


    def createSparkContext(): StreamingContext = {

      val conf = new SparkConf()
        .setAppName("c Events Processing")
        .setMaster("local[2]")
        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", cassandraHost)
        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.keep_alive_ms", "60000") // prevent cassandra connection from being closed after every write

      val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
      // Create the context
      val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(8))
      val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);

      // Kafka stream
      val kafkaParams = Map[String, String]("metadata.broker.list" -> brokers)
      val topicsSet = topics.split(",").toSet
      val cEvents = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet).map(_._2)

      cEvents.foreachRDD { rdd =>
        count = count + 1
        sqlContext.read.json(rdd).registerTempTable("eventTable")

        val eventdf1 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM eventTable")


        eventdf1.collect.foreach(println)

        val eventdf = sqlContext.sql("SELECT sensor, sendtime,data.actor FROM eventTable")
        eventdf.printSchema()
        eventdf.map {
          case (r) => (r.getString(0) + count, sendtime, count,eventdf1)
        }
          .saveToCassandra("c", "event", SomeColumns("sensor", "sendtime", "count","entireJson"))

      }


      ssc

    }


  }
```

Comment: whats your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this , and it works to save rawdata into my Cassandras Table Column.

```
 var rawdata = ""
        for (item <- rdd.collect().toArray) {
          System.out.println(item);
          rawdata = item
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

create one entity class then map it table . using this you can directly store RDD into cassandra database .
==check following link 
https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/6_advanced_mapper.md